# Phonegap: Something Faster than touchstart() function?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm writing a phonegap app and I discovered the function touchstart which speeds up the clicks in the application but it isn't still realtime responsive...
Can I speed things up a little bit?
I heard of fastclick.js but is has the same effect as the touchstart() function..

Does anybody know something faster?

I cannot click more than 2-3 times per second with these variants.

#### Update

I tried jGestures and it seems is exactly the same as fastclick and touchstart function.. The problem was that I tested the responsiveness through a sound and the mp3 had a few milliseconds of unrecorded sound... That was actually the lag... After I edited the mp3 its fully realtime responsive!

Comment: Then `touchstart` `touchend` should work normally without the need to load extra plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [jGestures](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/) in all my projects (and yes, it depends on jQuery).

It has "real" touch events with the "tapone" event. Besides that, it have a lot other events you can use. Like swipe events.

You use it as a normal event:

```
$(el).bind("tapone", function(){
    console.log("tap tap");
});
```